# Executing next task first when firebase forEach loop has finished

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I have two tasks. They have to get values from Firebase Firestore. Here is my JavaScript:

```
if (doc.exists) {
            console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
            const data = doc.data();
            const members = data.members;
            var permission_table = document.getElementById("noten_tabelle_permission");
            var permission_table_container = document.getElementById("main_padding");

            members.forEach(el => {
              console.log(el)

              table_number++;

              const html = fillTemplate("grade_table" + table_number, doc.id);
              // Join the array of html and add it as the `innerHTML` of `main`
              document.getElementById("main_padding").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);

              db.collection("users").doc(el).collection("grades").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                    const data = doc.data();

                    addToTable("grade_table" + table_number, doc.id, data.mdl, data.klu);

                });
              });
            })

          } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
          }
```

So first as you can see I am getting the "members" from Firestore. Then I create for each one a table with a different id. By the way. Here is the "fillTemplate" Function:

```
function fillTemplate({ table_name, id }) {
  return `
  <div class="noten_tabelle_permission" id="noten_tabelle_permission">
    <h1 id="member_name">${id}</h1>
    <table id="${table_name}" style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Fach</th>
        <th>mündlich</th>
        <th>Klausur</th>
      </tr>
      <!-- Make content with js code -->
    </table>
  </div>
  `;
}
```

So after joining table to main view, I am searching for each user ( === or for each table) the values. I add them to the table by calling the "addToTable" function, you can see here:

```
function addToTable(table_name, subject, mdl, klu) {

  var subject_name = getSubjectByNumber(subject);
  var short_subject = getSubjectShortByNumber(subject);

      var y = document.createElement([short_subject]);
      y.setAttribute("id", [short_subject]);
      document.getElementById([table_name]).appendChild(y);

      var y = document.createElement("TR");
      y.setAttribute("id", [short_subject]);

      var cE = document.createElement("TD");
      var tE = document.createTextNode([subject_name]);
      cE.appendChild(tE);
      y.appendChild(cE);

      var a = document.createElement("TD");
      var b = document.createTextNode([mdl]);
      a.appendChild(b);
      y.appendChild(a);

      var c = document.createElement("TD");
      var d = document.createTextNode([klu]);
      c.appendChild(d);
      y.appendChild(c);


      document.getElementById(table_name).appendChild(y);
}
```

But now I am getting this Error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null` in this line: `document.getElementById([table_name]).appendChild(y);`. I think it is because Firebase is asynchronous. But how to fix this? How to code it that it strictly get the values for the member and start first than with the next member?

---

The id of the tables is the string "grade_table" and the number of the var table_number. The id is needed even for the second firebase task. But since the first Firebase task loads asynchronous the var table_number is updated instantly with this line: table_number++;. So the next task of firebase has the wrong table id.

---

~marcelo

Comment: It looks like `document.getElementById(table_name)` returns `null`. As far as I can see this is not related to asynchronous loading of data, since you create the table before trying to populate it. Can you see which specific value of `table_name` name triggers it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Ye that is the point. The id of the tables is the string "grade_table" and the number of the var table_number. The id is needed even for the second firebase task. But since the first Firebase task loads asynchronous the var table_number is updated instantly with this line: `table_number++;`. So the next task of firebase has the wrong table id.

Comment: Ah... I think the trick is to define a function for the nested operation and pass the correct value into a function in that case. So in that case you'd capture the value in the closure. See http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is there no way without this? Or how would it looks like on my code?